# What is it that makes Stack Overflow so great?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [This place is AWESOME!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27269/this-place-is-awesome)
>   [Why does Stack Overflow work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16250/why-does-stack-overflow-work)

I know a *few* sites where you give a hand to people and get help from other developers,
but none of them are a match for Stack Overflow!!!

What is it that makes this very web site so nice to use, where even wandering about is pleasing?

Is it,

- its clear and sober presentation?
- its valuable content that saves time 
  to all of us when entering panic-mode ? ;-)
- its great community, composed
  mainly of specialists who often
  know something that you don't?

Maybe a bit of all of this?

Comment: Heh, sober.  Then there's meta.

Comment: Tom, If you have 200 rep on SO, then you can associate accounts here and get 100 rep.

Comment: @Renesis: Since you rephrased the question, all the answers have now become irrelevant. :-(

Comment: Possibly related: [Why is Stack Overflow so addicting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56469/what-aspects-of-psychology-does-stack-overflow-take-advantage-of/56810#56810)  :)

Comment: @Siva Actually, I just made the title match the body.  Most of the answerers didn't read it, apparently. But oh well.

Comment: Shouldn't this be closed?

Comment: The *primary* thing that makes it better is that it's strictly moderated, both through human actions, automated scripts, and a precise charter embodying basic expectations. There's a very high signal-to-noise ratio, and crap gets cleaned up very quickly. The focus is on *answers*, and good quality ones, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is it that makes this very web site so nice to use, where even wandering about is pleasing?

The voting. No really, hear me out...

On SO, all of the "thanks!" noise from the old-school forums and mail lists — and much of the flamewarring  — is nicely condensed into a vote on the question or answer. The voting on answers also acts as a filter, most people know they can read the first one or two and skim the rest (makes "wandering about" nice). It also encourages decoupling of answers from each other ie. they are not replies in a discussion, which further quashes flamewars and focuses content. The reward of personal recognition attracts people who actually know what they're talking about. It also means that instead of organising information by time, it can be organised by... actual information content!

This all leads to a relatively high signal-to-noise ratio for the whole site. This, in turn, allows for a cleanness of presentation that is absolutely impossible on, say, a threaded email discussion or a forum with posts stapled together one after another.

Using time as the sole dimension for organisation restricts how a site can be presented and used. **Voting adds another dimension**, which means that strange new interface and design decisions are possible (and even suggest themselves).

Answer (score 5):

I hate it. Meta is **so** much better.

Comment: StackOverflow is like a wannabe meta, except they talk about some boring code.

Comment: @compwhizii Nah, meta is soooo meta.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Comment: You're biased diamond boy :)

Comment: @squillman Leave [Neil](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwircEDCss8) out of this!

Comment: Hah!  I **KNEW** it!

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow is alright, but I don't think I've ever heard of this SatckOverflow.  Is it a clone?

Comment: Lol @ the downvotes.  Check the question's edit history.

Comment: fixed the down vote ;) my humble +1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can't put into words how much I love SO. A bug I've been having for three months just got solved for me in one line of code... beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

The democratic community that based on voting and reputation system make the Stackoverflow so great, I think.

PS: Stackoverflow responds new requriments is so fast. you can find the answer in [Jeff's Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/).